# Changing Table Content: AJAX Request vs. JQuery - Performance

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Basically I have a table as follows. Using Bootstrap-table and an AJAX request to get the user contents in JSON format.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Username  | Email            | Role    |  State    |
------------------------------------------------------
| Joe       | joe@mail.com     | Admin   |  Normal   |
------------------------------------------------------
| Peter     | peter@mail.com   | Member  |  Locked   |
------------------------------------------------------
| Jason     | jason@mail.com   | Member  |  Locked   |
------------------------------------------------------
|   ....    |    ..........    |  .....  |   .....   |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Let's say I update user 'Joe' and change his details via a pop-up form. Would it be better to reflect the data in the table via an

1. AJAX table refresh - The AJAX call requests a file with user data around 5kb of data for 20 records, depending on the user data. This request is also done for delete/add/update in order to reflect new changes.
2. Change the table contents through JQuery without refreshing the page by either deleting the row adding a new row or updating an existing row.

I think the second option is more recommend as it saves 1kb - 5kb each time an operating is triggered. However this would make increase the page size due to additional JQuery code.

Anyone can suggest what is the ideal option, and whether I can approach this in another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with a restful API, you should PUT the updated User object to the server which in turn should return it back if it was succesfully updated in the database – otherwise it should throw an error at you. Use this returned object to edit the row (or show an error message if an error is thrown).

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear. What I meant was would it be better to reflect the changes by refreshing the table data using a GET request or by  updating the table data by changing on the client side?

Comment: What if the update to the database was unsuccessful? The user would see an updated view, but wouldn't be aware the the changes didn't go through to the server.

Comment: I'm already handling those situations using success/error and http status codes. I only update the table if the request was successful otherwise errors are shown on the view while the table remains unchanged.